# Django Celery maximum recursion depth exceede

Tags: django, django-views, django-celery

Tring out Django Celery for the first time, new to Django and Celery.

Below is what I have so far trying I get the following error...

**RuntimeError at /contacts/upload
maximum recursion depth exceeded**

I'm using SQS and the message broker.

**settings.py**

```
# Celery

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'south',
    'userena',
    'social_auth',
    'djcelery',


)

BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'sqs'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'eu-west-1',
    }
BROKER_USER = 'xyz'
BROKER_PASSWORD = 'zyx'
```

**tasks.py**

```
@task
def upload(request, **kwargs):
    file = request.FILES['file']
    ContactCSVModel.import_from_file(file)
    return True
```

**view.py**

```
@login_required
def upload(request):

            result = upload(request)
            if result:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Items have been added to the database.')
        else:

         etc
```

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task and your view are called *exactly* the same thing.

So when you do this:

```
result = upload(request)
```

You're not calling your task, as I think you expect, you're calling your view function again. And again. And again. And again.

Try changing your view def to:

```
def upload_file(request):
```

The should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your task:

```
@task
def upload_task():
    ...

def upload(request):
    result = upload_task(request)
```

If view and task has the same name, inside upload view, when upload called, upload is the upload view itself.